# When there is an avatar of Goddess Parvati holding Lord Kartikeya called Skandmata, why is there no avatar of Goddess Parvati holding Lord Ganesh?

Tags: ganesha, durga, parvati, kartikeya, navrathri

Goddess Durga's fifth form is called Skandmata, and she holds Lord Kartikeya. However, despite the many stories of Goddess and her love for Lord Ganesh, there is no avatar of her holding Lord Ganesh. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't found the exact verses but it's there it's mata Vishalakshi also called as ganeshmata. Here is her pic.

[image]

Comment: Well it's better than nothing still I will try and search for the verses. ..

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this avatar.

Comment: @curiousseeker you are most welcome buddy. But I saw this ditto question in Quora also and answered it like this only. Was that you.? Anyways man tc. ..

Comment: @Savdy- No, it wasn't me. Maybe someone else out there is thinking the same way :-)

Comment: @curiousseeker no dude, I think he copied ur question from here and paste it there, it's exactly the same. [See](https://www.quora.com/When-there-is-an-avatar-of-Goddess-Parvati-holding-Lord-Kartikeya-called-Skandmata-why-is-there-no-avatar-of-Goddess-Parvati-holding-Lord-Ganesh) for youself. .